# Take first value of a column based on groupby of another

Tags: qliksense

I'm struggling in finding the right way to achive this result: I would like to have the first value of a column related to a "group by" column.
Suppose that original table has 3 columns: a, b, c. I want to aggregate by the column b and have the first value of c.

[image]

I have tried to use the function below, but it doesn't work as I expect:

```
Aggr(nodistinct[c],[b])
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi you haven't specify where you want to achieve that - in script or in chart/table.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you need to use FirstSortedValue in table:

```
FirstSortedValue(c,c)
```

Here is a link to example qliksense app (I put your data and saved it on my OneDrive):

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am4ZTQ8qcLwRtACt1wAoUTdFZ6lt

If you need to implement it in your loading script you can use the same function.